# how to initialize a 2d vector of unique_ptrs using it's constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2019, stdvector, unique-ptr

I'm trying to initialize a 2d vector of unique_ptrs to set it's sizes and each index to nullptr
or if i want to some Base class object pointer but it doesn't work.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
}

int main()
{
    int m_width = 150, m_length = 13;

    vector <vector <std::unique_ptr<Base>>> m_board;

    m_board(m_length, vector < std::unique_ptr<Base>(m_width, nullptr));
}
```

also tried this method and still nothing:

```
m_board(m_length, vector < std::unique_ptr<Base>(std::move(m_width, nullptr)));
```

and this way too:

```
m_board(m_length, vector < std::unique_ptr<Base>(std::move(std::make_unique(m_width, nullptr))));
```

still nothing is working yet, for now i use a very ugly function with two for loops to do it
but i'm sure there is a way to make this work by using the constructor of both vectors and unique_ptr..
any ideas?

Comment: With or without `unique_ptr`, you do not resize() (hint) an already created `vector` this way.

Comment: so you think i should resize it in a for loop the regular way? is it pointless to use the constructor in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

First, if the `std::vector` is already constructed, to change the size of the `vector` is done by using `std::vector::resize`.  Your code was mixing up construction with sizing an already constructed vector.

The second thing is that the second argument to the [two-argument vector constructor (see (4))](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) is now an allocator for C++ 14 or greater, not the default value.

Thus the easiest way to set up the vector is to first `resize` the outer vector, and then `resize` each of the inner vector's in a loop individually:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
};

int main()
{
    int m_width = 150, m_length = 13;

    // Create a vector with m_length size 
    std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>> m_board(m_length);

    // individually resize the inner dimensions
    for (auto& m : m_board)
       m.resize(m_width);
}
```

Comment: Even in C++14, `vector` still has a constructor overload that takes a default element value as an input parameter (see [constructor (3)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)), eg: `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>> m_board(m_length, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>(m_width, nullptr));` I would suggest cleaning this up a little with some `using` statements: `using BasePtr = std::unique_ptr<Base>; using BasePtrVec = std::vector<BasePtr>; std::vector<BasePtrVec> m_board(m_length, BasePtrVec(m_width, nullptr));`

Comment: But that constructor makes **copies** of the value.